# Limit 7-Zip archive splitting to set number of revisions for backup

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, 7zip, revision

I am trying to create a batch script to take a directory within Windows, and compress it with 7-zip using a batch script, but limit the maximum file size of each compression part to max 4GB each, limiting the total amount of revision compression sets to 7 (for a weekly backup, Monday to Sunday).  The oldest will be removed on the next backup job.

I tried playing with the REM CHECK FOR REVISIONS code, but am not knowledgeable enough to understand how to proceed with this.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Script created for AVIMark Backup
REM Install 7-zip and make sure to create an environment variable to     allow for shortcuts
REM https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
REM set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
REM echo %PATH%
REM 7z

REM 7ZIP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE PATH
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
7z
cls

REM SET SOURCE, DESTINATION AND REVISION AMOUNT VARIABLES
SET source="C:\AVImark"
SET destination="C:\AVImarkBackup"
SET revisions=7

REM Change Directory to the source data folder
cd "%source%"

REM Run the command to compress the directory, gather the date stamp and insert compressed file into destination folder
7z a -r -v4g "%destination%\%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4% Backup".7z

REM CHECK FOR REVISIONS
cd "%destination%"
for /f "skip=%revisions% eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.7z') do @del "%%F"
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

I'd like to have every backup set (in its date format) to be limited to 7 revisions in total.

ie:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o7ji.jpg

ACTUAL RESULTS

There is no revision check and cleanup happening on the oldest job, it keeps adding more sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Script created for AVIMark Backup
rem Install 7-zip and make sure to create an environment variable to allow for shortcuts
rem https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
rem set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
rem echo %PATH%
rem 7z

rem 7ZIP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE PATH
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

rem SET SOURCE, DESTINATION AND REVISION AMOUNT VARIABLES
set "source=C:\AVImark"
set "destination=C:\AVImarkBackup"
set "revisions=7"
set "datestamp=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"

rem Change Directory to the source data folder
pushd "%source%" && (
    rem Run the command to compress the directory, gather the date stamp and insert compressed file into destination folder
    7z a -r -v4g "%destination%\%datestamp% Backup.7z"
    popd
)

rem CHECK FOR REVISIONS
pushd "%destination%" && (
    rem Option 1
    rem Delete by last modified filedate
    forfiles /d -7 /m "*Backup.7z.*" /c "cmd /c echo del @path"

    rem Or use:

    rem Option 2
    rem Delete by logged date. Requires datestamp yyyy-MM-dd for correct sorting
    if exist Backup.log (
        findstr /c:"%datestamp%" Backup.log || >> Backup.log echo %datestamp%
    ) else (
        > Backup.log echo %datestamp%
    )

    for /f "skip=%revisions% delims=" %%A in ('type Backup.log ^| sort /r') do (
        echo del "%%~A Backup.7z.*"
    )

    popd
)
```

Changed datestamp to `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `dd.MM.yyyy`.
The former datestamp is better for sorting.
If you want a datestamp independant of locale, search for
`wmic os get localdatetime` commands on this site.

Use of `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`.
The use of `&&` is to run following command if the last command was successful.
`||` is to run following command if the last command failed.

2 options are offered for use to delete the revisions:

1. The 1st is the use of `forfiles`.
    Currently as set, it will delete revisions older
    than 7 days from the current date.
    This might be suitable, unless no backups have been
    done for 7 days which may result in no backups.
2. The 2nd is the use of `Backup.log`.
   The date is appended to the log file and then the
   `for` loop reads the log file with `type`, and `sort`
   reverses the sort to make the oldest 1st and latest
   last. The `skip` avoids the processing of the 1st
   7 revisions. The rest will be used to delete the
   archives by the file pattern.

Remove the code of the option not wanted.

`del` commands are echoed for testing. If satisfied,
remove the echoes to make the deletion actually work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Micheal_heath!